# How to fix time exceeded execution exception while calling netsuite restlet

Tags: stack-overflow, netsuite

I got the exception time exceeded execution while calling the restlet api from postman or other external souce.

Answer (score 0):

That means your suitescript is processing too much data and possibly hitting the governance limit

avoid unnecessary module operations as follows:

- too many `record.load`
- nested queries. this will kill your governance
- processing >299 record operations in one restlet call. use a map reduce script instead
- loading transaction records and not using 'mainline' filter accordingly. this can bring back 1000's of records, thus resulting in your error

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you are not returning anything from your RESTlet function.